# Игра змейка. Не обновляет значение координат. JS

Tags: javascript

Змейка, головой которой служит нулевой элемент массива. При изменении направления снова начинает ползти из той точки, где была голова при старте. Кто нибудь подскажите, почему так, буду благодарен.

```js
let field = 0;
let direction = "right";

function createField() {
  field = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(field);
  field.classList.add("field");

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let excel = document.createElement('div');
    field.appendChild(excel);
    excel.classList.add("excel");
  }
  return (field);
}

createField();

let excelList = field.children;

let x = 0;
let y = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < excelList.length; i++) {
  x++;
  excelList[i].setAttribute("data-X", x);
  excelList[i].setAttribute("data-Y", y);
  if (x > 10) {
    x = 1;
    y--;
    excelList[i].setAttribute("data-X", x);
    excelList[i].setAttribute("data-Y", y);
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let snake = [];
let randX = getRandomInt(4, 9);
let randY = getRandomInt(4, 9);
let elemThree = document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 3) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]');
snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 1) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 2) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(elemThree);
for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  snake[i].classList.add("snake_body");
  snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  snake[0].classList.remove("snake_body");
}

let snakeCoordinates = [snake[0].getAttribute("data-X")];
console.log("snakeCoordinatea=" + snakeCoordinates);

function move() {
  snake[0].classList.remove("snake_head");
  snake[0].classList.add("snake_body");
  let b = snake.length - 1;
  snake[b].classList.remove("snake_body");
  snake.pop();
  if (direction == "right") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-X");
    if (a < 10) {
      a++;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 1;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    }
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "left") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-X");
    if (a > 1) {
      a--;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 10;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    }
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "up") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-Y");
    if (a < 10) {
      a++;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 1;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    }
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "down") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-Y");
    if (a > 1) {
      a--;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 10;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    }
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  }
}

let interval = setInterval(move, 1000);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
    direction = "up";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
    direction = "right";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
    direction = "down";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
    direction = "left";
  }
  console.log("snakeCoordinates=" + snakeCoordinates);
});
```

```css
.field {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.excel {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.snake_head {
  background-image: url("img/snake.svg");
}

.snake_body {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let field = 0;
let direction = "right";

function createField() {
  field = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(field);
  field.classList.add("field");

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let excel = document.createElement('div');
    field.appendChild(excel);
    excel.classList.add("excel");
  }
  return (field);
}

createField();

let excelList = field.children;

let x = 0;
let y = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < excelList.length; i++) {
  x++;
  excelList[i].setAttribute("data-X", x);
  excelList[i].setAttribute("data-Y", y);
  if (x > 10) {
    x = 1;
    y--;
    excelList[i].setAttribute("data-X", x);
    excelList[i].setAttribute("data-Y", y);
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let snake = [];
let randX = getRandomInt(4, 9);
let randY = getRandomInt(4, 9);
let elemThree = document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 3) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]');
snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 1) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + (randX - 2) + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
snake.push(elemThree);
for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  snake[i].classList.add("snake_body");
  snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  snake[0].classList.remove("snake_body");
}

let snakeCoordinates = [snake[0].getAttribute("data-X")];
console.log("snakeCoordinatea=" + snakeCoordinates);

function move() {
  snake[0].classList.remove("snake_head");
  snake[0].classList.add("snake_body");
  let b = snake.length - 1;
  snake[b].classList.remove("snake_body");
  snake.pop();
  if (direction == "right") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-X");
    if (a < 10) {
      a++;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 1;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    }
    randX = a;
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "left") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-X");
    if (a > 1) {
      a--;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 10;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + a + '"][data-Y="' + randY + '"]'));
    }
    randX = a;
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "up") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-Y");
    if (a < 10) {
      a++;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 1;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    }
    randY = a;
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  } else if (direction == "down") {
    let a = +snake[0].getAttribute("data-Y");
    if (a > 1) {
      a--;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    } else {
      a = 10;
      snake.unshift(document.querySelector('[data-X="' + randX + '"][data-Y="' + a + '"]'));
    }
    randY = a;
    snake[0].classList.add("snake_head");
  }
}

let interval = setInterval(move, 1000);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
    direction = "up";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
    direction = "right";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
    direction = "down";
  } else if (event.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
    direction = "left";
  }
  console.log("snakeCoordinates=" + snakeCoordinates);
});
```

```css
.field {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.excel {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.snake_head {
  background-image: url("img/snake.svg");
}

.snake_body {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```